# What is the difference when importing components in computed and components in vuejs dynamic import?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Consider I have 4 components inside a page/component which user can use depends upon their selection (for ex:- toggle between Input comp || Image Comp || Video Comp || Vudio Comp ). I can lazily load them in two ways which is

1)

```
<template>
  <component :is="compName">
</template>
data: () => ({compName: 'input'}),
components: {
 input: () => import('/components/input'),
 video: () => import('/components/video'),
 audio: () => import('/components/audio'),
 image: () => import('/components/image'),
}
```

2)

```
<template>
  <component :is="loadComp">
</template>
data: () => ({compName: 'input'}),
computed: {
 loadComp () {
  const compName = this.compName
  return () => import(`/components/${compName}`)
 }
}
```

What difference will it make? Which is the correct way of dynamic import?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Main difference** is that in second case, Webpack does not know at build time what `compName` value can be at runtime so it will automatically **create separate bundle for every file** in `/components/` folder.

From [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)

> The import() must contain at least some information about where the module is located. Bundling can be limited to a specific directory or set of files so that when you are using a dynamic expression - every module that could potentially be requested on an `import()` call is included. For example, `import('./locale/${language}.json')` will cause every `.json` file in the `./locale` directory to be bundled into the new chunk. At run time, when the variable language has been computed, any file like `english.json` or `german.json` will be available for consumption.

You can tune what should be included and what not with ["magic comments"](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) tho. For example following will bundle only `.json` files from the folder

```js
import(
  /* webpackInclude: /\.json$/ */
  `./locale/${language}`)
```

If that's what you want, both are valid and right ways to do dynamic imports. Second one with obvious advantage that you don't need to write imports one by one....

**Second** big difference is in the 1st case components are registered and you can use their names in the template as normal:

```html
<template>
  <input />
  <video />
</template>
```

...whereas component resolved as in 2nd case is not registered and can be only used in `<component :is="computed" />`

Comment: Levy.Thanks. one doubt ,Please give an example for the below line ( You can tune what should be included and what not with "magic comments" tho (chapter right below) )